# Using later defined macro values

Tags: macros

Is there a way to get something like

```
\test
\newcommand{\test}{Print me!}
```

to work in the same manner as

```
\newcommand{\test}{Print me!}
\test
```

would work? Basically I'm wondering if I can set a macro or a predefined value in something that executes in a compile phase and then displays properly if I use it before its defined in the LaTeX file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!. No, it's impossible this way. But you can use the `.aux` file for the macro `\test` have the desired value at the next run of LaTeX. Can you please be some more specific about your need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TeX is like a one-way street when it starts compiling. So you'll have to use alternative means (including alternative macro usages) to achieve what you're after.

Below the command `\laterdef` acts like a "`\label`" which writes a `g`lobal (re)`def`inition to the `.aux` *immediately*. First compilation yields `abc` for `\test` while subsequent compilations output `def`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand{\test}{abc}% Create \test to be abc

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\laterdef}[2]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\gdef\string#1{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test

\laterdef{\test}{def}% Overwrite \test to be def

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` is read in as part of `\begin{document}`. So, any redefinition of `\test` between `\begin{document}` and `\test` will nullify the use of `\laterdef`.

Without `\providecommand{\test}`, you'll receive an error during the first compile.

Comment: What if `#2` contains fragile stuff? Try `\laterdef{\test}{\textbf{def}}` for example... Instead of `\robustify`ing the macro name only I'd wrap everything with `\unexpanded`: `\immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\gdef#1{#2}}}`

Comment: You should use `\protected@write`; the `\robustify` part is useless: just say `\gdef\string#1{#2}`. Since `\gdef` is not expandable it is written as is and `\string` in front of it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out issues... I've updated the post.

Comment: Actually, `\protected@write` expands everything except `\protect`ed tokens (but it defers expansion of `\thepage` until the `\shipout`); also, its `\write` is not `\immediate`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti It's *good* that `\protected@write` is not immediate *and* doesn't expand `\thepage`. Any reference to the page number in the replacement text of `\laterdef` could not be trusted on. Of course, knowing better what the OP has in mind would allow better analysis.

Comment: @egreg: I didn’t say that `\protected@write` is not good, neither I meant it.  (*Anything* coming from you is “good” almost by definition! ;-)  I just wanted to clarify the point, given the previous reference to `\unexpanded`.

Answer (score 6):

First of all I want to underline that LaTeX already has a mechanism for the most frequent cases when “delayed definitions” are needed. If you want to use a generated number even before the place where it's generated, or the page number where the event occurs, you just place `\label{<string>}` after the command that generates the number and you can print the generated number by `\ref{<string>}` or the page number by `\pageref{<string>}`.

A generated number is, for instance, a section number or the item number in an `enumerate` and so on.

It's not possible to use a command before it has been defined, because TeX proceeds with tokens one at a time (and macros can change their meaning any time). The mechanism above works by writing a note in the `.aux` file, so the “delayed item” will be known only at the next LaTeX run. This might look annoying, but no document is ever finished at the first LaTeX run, so this is really not a problem.

You can even abuse the above mechanism:

```
\newcounter{laterdef} % just a dummy counter
\newcommand{\laterdef}[2]{%
  \renewcommand\thelaterdef{#2}%
  \refstepcounter{laterdef}\label{#1}%
}
```

Here's a full example, where the text has special commands (accents here) to show that no particular protection is needed in general; some commands may need `\protect` in front of them (look on the site for “fragile command”).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{laterdef} % just a dummy counter
\newcommand{\laterdef}[2]{%
  \renewcommand\thelaterdef{#2}%
  \refstepcounter{laterdef}\label{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

This is some text where we want to
use something that will be known only
later: \ref{test}.

Here is text that follows.

Now we define the contents needed
above.

\laterdef{test}{Na\"ive Stra\ss e}

\end{document}
```

During the LaTeX run you may see the following messages on the console:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `test' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

If you later change the text in `\laterdef`, you'll just see the last message; the first two happens when a reference is not yet known.

The first LaTeX run will produce

[image]

where the unknown text has been replaced by **??**

The next LaTeX run will produce instead

[image]

If you're bold and want to define a mechanism yourself, you can:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lateruse}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{late@#1}{??}{\@nameuse{late@#1}}%
}
\newcommand\laterdef[2]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \global\string\@namedef{late@#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is some text where we want to
use something that will be known only
later: \lateruse{test}.

Here is text that follows.

Now we define the contents needed
above.

\laterdef{test}{Na\"ive Stra\ss e}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why isn’t the “space hack” appropriate in this case?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti It would require explanations and I don't think it's the best way to cope with the problem anyway.